# Sorting hex color values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, colors, hex

I have a MySQL table named hexcodetable with just one column named hexcode of type VARCHAR(100). The table contains all hex color codes. The rows are populated as six-character hexadecimal numbers preceded by a #. For instance, #25F412. How can we sort all the rows from most black to most white such that the first row will be #000000, the second #000001 and the last one #FFFFFF? Note that I don't necessarily mean a numerical sort.

Comment: `order by hexcode` doesn't work?

Comment: Absolutely not. That returns #000000 as the first row which is correct, but it starts to go wrong where it returns the second row as #10000 whereas it should be #000001

Comment: If the column is a VarChar (btw, why it's a VarChar(100) instead of a Char(6) or binary?) it will sort the correct way: #000000, #000001, #000002

Comment: Char(6) wouldn't work. Remember all the values in the rows begin with a #. I guess VARCHAR(100) is just for the purposes of playing it safe.

Comment: Try converting it to an actual number. Something like `UNHEX(SUBSTR(col_name,2))`.

Comment: @MugaS. . . . `order by hexcode` works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4147392268b17d3c60d33536bb20ee41.

Comment: If every value begin with a `#` there's no need to store it. Display should be seperate from storage. And 3 bytes should be stored in 3 bytes, not 6 or 7 or 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a numerical sort by the hexadecimal value. How about

```
Select hexcode from hexcodetable order by Conv(substring(hexcode,2,6),16,10)
```

Comment: Substring in MySQL starts from 1, not 0. It needs to be `substring(hexcode,2,6)`.

Comment: Thanks Vatev. I missed that.

Comment: You convert a string to another string trimming off the leading zeroes and now you sort: `1, 11, 111, 2`. In fact the original data sorts correct.

Comment: Baffled dnoeth. Your comment has nothing to do with my proposed answer which is to sort by the hexadecimal value by converting hex to base 10.